# MySQL запрос: пересечение диапазонов

Tags: множества, математика, mysql, запрос, sql

Здравствуйте.

Есть таблица обуви ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36fb2)):

```
id | size_min | size_max
 1 |       10 |       25
 2 |       15 |       20
 3 |       20 |       30
 4 |        5 |       10
```

Это значит, что, к примеру, ботинки #1 имеются размеров 10, 11, 12, 13, ... 25.

И есть фильтр по размерам: указывается тоже минимальный интересующий размер и максимальный. Например так:

```
filter[size_min] = 15;
filter[size_max] = 22;
```

То есть, интересует вся обувь, размеры которой имеются:

```
id | size_min | size_max
 1 |       10 |       25
 2 |       15 |       20
 3 |       20 |       30
```

#1 попадает под условие, так как `[10, 25] ⋂ [15, 22] = [15, 22]`

#2 попадает под условие, так как `[15, 20] ⋂ [15, 22] = [15, 20]`

#3 попадает под условие, так как `[20, 30] ⋂ [15, 22] = [20, 22]`

#4 **не** попадает под условие, так как `[5, 10] ⋂ [15, 22] = []`, поэтому его не должно быть в результатах выборки.

Задача усложняется еще тем что один из поисковых параметров может быть не указан: `filter[size_max] = 22`, а `filter[size_min]` не указан. Или наоборот: `filter[size_min] = 15`, а `filter[size_max] = NULL`.

Понятно, для первого случая можно преобразовать 1 данный параметр в диапазон [0, 22]. По этой логике второй — в [15, +infinity]. Если это возможно, подскажите, как передать MySQL «бесконечность» или MAX_INTEGER.

Прошу помочь составить запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось проще. Запрос должен быть таким:

```
SELECT * FROM `shoes` WHERE
    `size_max` > 15
    AND
    `size_min` < 22
```

Если один из параметров фильтра не указан, можно его просто опустить:

```
SELECT * FROM `shoes` WHERE
    `size_max` > 15
```

При желании можно даже [определить пересечение](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36fb2/22).

[@KaZaца](/users/10548/kaza%D1%86%D0%B0) и [@ЫЫЫ](/users/7285/%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B), спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

принять за null бесконечность, проверка следующая
(:max is null or size_max < :max)

проверка снизу
(:min is null or size_min > :min)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from shoes where not ((size_min<:min and size_max<:min) or (size_min>:max and size_max>:max));
```

Думаю для любой предметной области можно найти недостижимое больше число и принять его за бесконечность. Хотя можно добавить в запрос:

```
...(size_min>:max and size_max>:max and :max<>-1)
```

,тогда отрезок [15,-1] будет иметь смысл луча неограниченного справа.